# Hint for Number Theory problem from Engel.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to solve :

> Given: $n>3$ prove that $2^n+1$ is not a power of $3$.

I just need a hint for this problem.I am trying to solve by thinking about divisibility and congruences but can't figure out the right direction.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Gerry Myerson's Answer to [this slightly more general Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164874/2x-3y-1-has-only-three-natural-pairs-as-solutions) quotes a nice exposition of the original proof due to [Gersonides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gersonides) in *The Harmony of Numbers* (1343).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $n$ is even $2^n$ is congruent to $1\bmod 3$.

If $n$ is odd you can write $2^n+1$ as $(2+1)(2^{n-1}-2^{n-2}+2^{n-3}\dots +1)$. Notice the first pair of terms is $1\bmod 3$, the second pair is also $1\bmod 3$. Therefore the part in the right is a multiple of three if and only if $n$ is a multiple of $3$.

But $2^{3k}+1=(2^k)^3+1=(2^k+1)(2^{2k}-2^k+1)$ So $2^k+1$ needs to be a power of $3$. Therefore if $k=9$ does not work we are done.

Comment: Beautiful and elegant.Exactly what I was waiting for.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** In order that $3\mid(2^n+1)$, $n$ must be odd. If $m,n$ are odd numbers and $m\mid n$, then $(2^m+1)\mid(2^n+1)$. Now have a look at [Zsigmondy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem), or prove that:
$$ \nu_2(3^k-1) \leq \nu_2(k)+2.$$

Comment: Can you make it more explicit and elementary.I am not getting Zsigmondy's theorem exactly.

Comment: The point is that, as $n$ is odd an increases, $2^n+1$ tends to have newer and newer prime factors.

Comment: Or, by using the other inequality, consider that if $2^n = 3^k-1$, then $k$ must be big, with a size comparable to $2^n$. But that contradicts equality.

Comment: That makes sense reading it again.Thanks Jack.

Comment: @DevarshRuparelia: you're welcome.