# Finding all natural number solutions to $2^{\lceil \log_2(3^x) \rceil} = 3^x + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Can someone help on how to find all natural number solutions to this following equation:
$$2^{\lceil \log_2(3^x) \rceil} = 3^x + 1$$

Obvious solution is $x = 1$.

Is there any other possible solution? If no other solution, any way we can proof it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164874/2x-3y-1-has-only-three-natural-pairs-as-solutions/164876#164876

Comment: The link by Kenta shows all cases where $3^x \pm 1$ is a power of $2$.  The only case with $3^x+1$ is your case $x=1$.  There are two more cases with $3^x-1$.