# Is this a valid argument to show that for $m > 4$, $2^m - 3^n \ne 7$

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Is the follow argument valid?  Is there a simpler argument?

Here's the argument:

(1)  Assume that there exists for integer $m > 4, n$:
$$2^m - 3^n = 7$$

(2)  $m$ and $n$ are even since:

$$2^{m} - 3^{n} \equiv 4 - 9 \equiv 7 \pmod {12}$$

(3)  So, there exists integers $i,j$ with $m=2i, n=2j$ with:

$$2^m - 3^n = (2^i - 3^j)(2^i + 3^j) = 7$$

(4) But, since $i > 2$, $2^i - 3^j \ne  1$ from the [Catalan's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture)

(5)  Then, both $2^i - 3^j$ and $2^i + 3^j$ are greater than $1$ which is impossible since $7$ is prime.  So we reject our assumption in step(1).

Comment: I would not use a conjeture to prove anything.

Comment: It’s much easier to show that $2^i+3^j\neq 7$ than it is to prove Catalan’s conjecture, I think. :)

Comment: @Ripi2 "Catalan's conjecture (or Mihăilescu's theorem) ..."

Comment: @Ripi2 Catalan's conjecture is just the name.  It was proven by Preda Mihăilescu in 2002.

Comment: @rtybase and Larry Freeman: Thanks.  A new thing I learned today.

Comment: @LarryFreeman but it is overkill for an elementary question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catalan’s conjecture is way overkill.

Since $2^i-3^j<2^i+3^j$ are integer and the second is positive, the only way for their product to be $7$ is if  $2^i+3^j=7.$ But $m\geq 6$ means $i\geq 3,$ so $$2^i+3^j>2^3=8>7.$$

However, Catalan might be needed to prove the more general result that there is no prime $p\equiv 7\pmod{12}$ and $m>4,n>0 $ such that:

$$p=2^m-3^n$$

**Edit:** (From commenter Erick Wong) It turns out, it is pretty easy to show there is no $2^i-3^j=1$ with $i>2$ just by looking modulo $8,$ so you don’t need Catalan for that, either.

Comment: Catalan isn't needed for the latter result either.  There is an elementary proof that $2^m - 3^n = 1$ has no solutions for $m\ge 3$: just look at the equation mod $8$.  Apparently this was already studied in the 14th century :).  Reference: https://mathoverflow.net/a/29928

Comment: Gerson's proof is also given in an [answer on this site in 2012](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/164874/242).

Answer (score 1):

Just a small alternative to Thomas Andrews's answer: If $(2^i-3^j)(2^i+3^j)=7$ then $2^i-3^j=1$ and $2^i+3^j=7$, which implies $2\cdot2^i=1+7=8$, or $i=2$ (corresponding to $m=2i=4$).