# Find integral solutions of $\left|3^{x}-2^{y}\right| = 1$

Tags: number-theory

> Find integral solutions of $\left|3^{x}-2^{y}\right| = 1$

---

In case of $3^{x}-2^{y}=1$, By putting values of x,y to be 0 we get it's not possible and x,y has to be greater than 0. So $3^{x}=1+2^{y} \rightarrow$ $1+2^{y} \equiv 0(\bmod 3)$ which means $y$ is odd. I'm stuck here and don't know what to do next.

Comment: See [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281292/are-there-infinitely-many-solutions-of-2k-3z-1-with-k-z-in-mathbbn?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164874/2x-3y-1-has-only-three-natural-pairs-as-solutions) form MSE.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very famous problem, but surprisingly I cannot find a duplicate.

I give here the sketch of a solution. You may try to fill in the details.

For $3^x - 2^y = 1$:

Try $y = 0, 1$ directly. Now suppose $y \geq 2$. Mod $4$ shows that $x$ is even. Rewrite the equation as $(3^{x/2} + 1)(3^{x/2} - 1) = 2^y$. Both factors on the left hand side are powers of two, while their difference is $2$.

For $2^y - 3^x = 1$:

Try $x = 0$ directly. Now suppose $x \geq 1$. Mod $3$ shows that $y$ is even. Do the same as above.

---

As a remark, this is a special case of [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) (now a theorem of Mihăilescu).

Comment: One of the duplicates is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164874/2x-3y-1-has-only-three-natural-pairs-as-solutions).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Indeed, I expected them to exist but somehow it's hard to find because the formulas are written in slightly different ways.

Comment: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clvert3%5E%7Bx%7D-2%5E%7By%7D%5Crvert%3D%201%24&p=1